# C# calling fortran dll stack overflow

Tags: c#, fortran, interop, pinvoke

I have a C# (NET 6) project where I try to call fortran subroutine and passing a `struct`.
I have made simplified version here:

c#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Console.WriteLine("C# starting");
Console.WriteLine($"Size of GrandParent: {Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(GrandParent))}");
var gp = new GrandParent();
Natives.SizeCheck(gp);

public static class Natives
{
    public const int MaxSize = 100;

    [DllImport(dllName: "FortranLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void SizeCheck(GrandParent gp);
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Child
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Natives.MaxSize)]
    internal double[] Array;
    public Child()
    {
        Array = new double[Natives.MaxSize];
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Parent
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Natives.MaxSize)]
    internal Child[] Children;

    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new Child[Natives.MaxSize];
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GrandParent
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Natives.MaxSize)]
    internal Parent[] Children;
    public GrandParent()
    {
        Children = new Parent[Natives.MaxSize];
    }
}
```

and the FortranLib.dll code:

```
module FortranLib
    use ISO_C_BINDING
    implicit none


   integer,parameter        ::  MaxSize = 100
   
   type, bind(C) :: Child
        real(C_DOUBLE)      ::  Array(MaxSize)
   end type Child
   
   type, bind(C) :: Parent
        type(Child)         ::  Children(MaxSize)
   end type Parent

   type, bind(C) :: GrandParent
        type(Parent)        ::  Children(MaxSize)
   end type GrandParent
   
    contains

    subroutine SizeCheck(gp)
     !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::SizeCheck
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE,ALIAS:"SizeCheck" :: SizeCheck
    ! Variables
    type(GrandParent), intent(in)   ::  gp
    ! Body of SizeCheck
    write(*,*) "In fortran dll first line"
    write(*,*) "Number of parents: ", size(gp%Children)
    write(*,*) "Number of children for each parent : ", size(gp%Children(0)%Children)
    write(*,*) "Size of child array : ", size(gp%Children(0)%Children(0)%Array)
    
    end subroutine SizeCheck
end module FortranLib
```

Using a `MaxSize = 45` works but not 46. From 46 and up I get a "Stack overflow" exception / crash. At 45 the size of GrandParent is 729000.
I have tried to set, in Visual Studio 2022 under the fortran project properties, Configuration Properties -> Optimization -> Heap Arrays = 0 (for always allocate arrays on heap) as well as Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack Reserve Size = 100000000 which I thought would be enough, but to no avail.

I start to think that it should be done in the c# project but where I do not know..
Anyone have an idea of what could be done?

##### EDIT 2022-09-09:

After adding `ref` to the `SizeCheck` parameter in c# it now works up to `MaxSize = 57` but larger values still crash with "Stack overflow".

After (for the first time) trying out disassembly window
I found that the error is thrown at the second to last line shown here ( `00007FF8CB397F98 E8 73 FC FF FF       call        CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@7ff8cb397c10 (07FF8CB397C10h)` ):

```
5: var gp = new GrandParent();
00007FF8CB397F8B 48 8D 4D 78          lea         rcx,[rbp+78h]  
00007FF8CB397F8F E8 BC F4 FF FF       call        Method stub for: GrandParent..ctor() (07FF8CB397450h)  
     6: Natives.SizeCheck(ref gp);
00007FF8CB397F94 48 8D 4D 78          lea         rcx,[rbp+78h]  
00007FF8CB397F98 E8 73 FC FF FF       call        CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@7ff8cb397c10 (07FF8CB397C10h)  
00007FF8CB397F9D 90                   nop
```

I am a n00b when it comes to disassembly but perhaps it gives someone else a clue...

Comment: Does `use ISO_C_BINDING` mean _Use CDecl calling convention_?  Despite the universality of the C language, not that many languages use CDecl.  Screwing up the calling convention is very quick way to mess up your stack.  You may want to include the `pinvoke` tag as well as the `interop` tag - it's more specific to your situation

Comment: @Flydog57 I am actually not entirely sure.I just read some years ago this was the way and have used that ever since, in many different situations but never before encountered this situation (stack overflow). I will need to double check. Thanks

Comment: Calling conventions can be weird (for example some specify "do this until XXX happens, then spill the rest over this other way).  They are a great way to mess up the stack.  I think there's a way to inject something into a call that verifies stack integrity before and after a P/Invoke call (for debugging purposes) - but that's a 15 or 20 year old memory.  You may find something by grocking the internet.  I came up with https://dotnetdebug.net/category/pinvoke/, but that doesn't look like it addresses your issue

Comment: How do you declare the SizeCheck dll import function in C#?

Comment: @SimonMourier - that is shown in the `Natives` class

Comment: @Flydog57 - This page confirms that Intel Fortran uses CDecl calling convention: http://www.luckingtechnotes.com/calling-fortran-dll-from-csharp/

Comment: Oh I missed it. Have you tried passing GrandParent as ref? Also are you building for x86 or x64?

Comment: @SimonMourier aaaaaah.. I am so stupid.. I was probably thinking too much in c# `class` reference-parameter not to think of `struct` as value parameter.... Thanks a ton! Do you wish to write a short answer? :)

Comment: The cdecl/stdcall distinction is only relevant in 32bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fortran compiler exposes the structure as a reference. This can be seen after (Intel here) compilation and disassembly below as `GRANDPARANT *GP`:

[image]

So the C# declaration should this instead:

```
public static extern void SizeCheck(ref GrandParent gp);
```

PS: the calling convention is not important in x64 (`fastcall` is [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#calling-convention-defaults))

To fix the stack overflow, you can either 1) change the maximum stack size compiled into your executable by using [EditBin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/editbin-reference) from the Visual Studio SDK like this for example (with 10Mb of stack):

```
EditBin.exe <your.exe> /stack:10000000
```

or 2) decide to marshal the big object "manually" like this:

```
var gp = new GrandParent();
var ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf<GrandParent>());
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(gp, ptr, false);
    Natives.SizeCheck(ptr);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
}
```

With the DllImport statement modified like this:

```
[DllImport("FortranLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SizeCheck(IntPtr gp);
```

Comment: This helped, now it works for sizes up to 57, where Size of GrandParent: 1560896

Comment: Didn't know about fastcall in x64 - do you mean that both intel fortran **and** c#/net calling convention is fastcall when x64?

Comment: By the way - How do you produce that nice view (your screendump)?

Comment: By default (and no one changes that in reality) yes, with x64 (on Microsoft tools & platforms including .NET: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832679/is-the-callingconvention-ignored-in-64-bit-net-applications) you don't have to bother with cdecl vs stdacall vs whatever, its all fastcall (follow the link in my answer). IDA Free: https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/